# Session not getting cleared in Yii

Tags: php, session, yii

I have a strange problem. I have a web application build in Yii.

Whenever i logout from the application the user is returned to the home page. However if i refresh the page. the user is logged in again.

Here is config file

```
'session' => array(
       'class'=>'CDbHttpSession',
        'timeout'=>$params['session_timeout'],
        'autoStart'=>true,
    ),
```

and here is my logout code

```
    Yii::app()->session->clear();
    Yii::app()->session->destroy();
    Yii::app()->cache->flush();
    Yii::app()->user->logout();
```

Recently i  noticed a file called session-1.1.8 in the runtime folder. it is not getting deleted at time of logout. how ever if i delete it manually,then user is logged out permanently.

So my Question is

1)Is there anything i am doing wrong here?

2)What is this "session-1.1.8" file ?

3)How can i logout permanently?

Comment: Ok. session-1.1.8.db file is coming when u am using CDbHttpSession. When i am using CHttpSession, it is not coming.

Comment: So I cannot delete this file, all users session will be lost?

Answer (score 1):

From Yii docs:

> By default, it will use an SQLite3 database named
>   'session-YiiVersion.db' under the application runtime directory. You
>   can also specify connectionID so that it makes use of a DB application
>   component to access database.

Thats were the file is comming from, try using your own `db` component and that should fixit.

`Yii::app()->user->logout();` already calls `Yii::app()->getSession()->destroy();`so you don't need to do it manually.

Comment: My application is running as rest client, i dont have any db on my side.

Comment: i have not initialized the db component in config/ main as well? what should i do for connectionID ?

Comment: How are you login in the user? perhaps something else is happening there then.

Comment: Actually i am calling rest api to check login credentials. also i have extended CWebUser

Comment: Can you check whats inside that sqlite3 database before/after you logout?

Answer (score 0):

I use this set and get very good:

```
'cache'=>array(
   'class' => 'CFileCache', 
),

'session' => array(
   'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
   'timeout' => 60*60*24*30*12*5, 
),
```

> 60*60*24*30*12*5 = 60 seconds, 60 minutes, 24 hours, 30 days, 12 monts, 5 years